# Iptables: Перенаправление трафика в зависимости от домена

Tags: iptables, домен, порт

Есть 2 домена domain.com и domain.ru, есть сервер с ОС Debian и iptables на борту.
Возможно ли перенаправлять входящий трафик на порт в зависимости от того, через какой домен идёт подключение?
Пример:
domain.com:7777 => 127.0.0.1:7777
domain.ru:7777 => 127.0.0.1:7778

Comment: Понятие домена в TCP-трафике в целом не существует и определено только для уровня приложения, и то главным образом для HTTP/HTTPS. Так что я бы посмотрел на application layer specific решения, например, на nginx.

Comment: На портах сервера 7777 и 7778 крутятся разные и независимые друг от друга приложения, поэтому для меня это неактуально.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл ответ на [англоязычном Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878541/routing-incoming-requests-to-specific-servers-based-on-domain-name), который помог.

Добавил SRV запись, направленную на нужный порт.

Comment: Это работает не со всеми протоколами и поддерживается не всеми клиентами